# Oracle : Drop multiple partitions

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning, partition

A table **TMP** has 5 partitions, namely P_1, P_2,....P_5.
I need to drop some partitions of **TMP**; the partitions to drop are derived by another query.

Ex:

```
ALTER TABLE TMP DROP PARTITIONS (SELECT ... From ...  //expression to get partition names )
```

Let's say the SELECT statement returns P_1 & P_5. The part query of the ALTER statement above doesn't work. Is there any way to drop partitions with input from a SELECT statement?

Comment: For this you have to use pl/sql block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dynamic sql` in `anonymous pl/sql` block;

```
Begin
  for i in (select part_name from ...  //expression to get partition names) loop
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE TMP DROP PARTITION ' || i.part_name;
  end loop;
end;
```

For dropping multiple partitions on a go then;

```
declare
  v_part varchar(1000);
Begin
  select LISTAGG(partition_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY partition_name DESC)
  into v_part  
  from ...  //expression to get partition names;
  execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE TMP DROP PARTITION ' || v_part;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following sql to generate DML for dropping multiple table partitions.

```sql
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || TABLE_OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ' DROP PARTITION ' || '"' || PARTITION_NAME || '";' from DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS 
where TABLE_NAME='%YOUR_PATTERN%'order by PARTITION_NAME;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, I found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL.  Something this:

```
begin
    for prec in (SELECT ... From ...  //expression to get partition names )
    loop
         execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE TMP DROP PARTITION '
             || prec.partition_name;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Clearly you need to have complete faith that your query will return only the partitions you want to drop.  Or equivalent faith in your Backup & Recover plans :)

Alternatively you can use a similar approach to generate a drop script which you can review before you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pl/sql block for dropping partitions from a table with select query. Use listagg for making a comma separated list.

```
 DECLARE
    var1 varchar2(50);
    BEGIN
    SELECT listagg(Partition_names) into var1  from table_name//expression to get partition names ;
    execute immediate 'alter table tmp drop PARTITION'||var1  ;
    END;
```

**Example on listagg**

```
select LISTAGG(partition_name,',') within group(order by table_name) as comma_list
 from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS where TABLE_owner='OWNER' AND TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's could somebody help.

This script drop all partitions for all partition tables for specific schema. I use it with clear DB with METADATA, for changing started (referencial) partition.

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1
  SET INTERVAL ();
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_1.TABLE_2
  SET INTERVAL ();
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_1.TABLE_3
  SET INTERVAL ();  

set lines 100

set heading off

spool runme.sql

select 'ALTER TABLE ' || TABLE_OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ' DROP PARTITION ' || '"' || PARTITION_NAME || '";' from DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS 
where 
    TABLE_OWNER='SCHEMA_1'
--    and TABLE_NAME='TABLE_%' 
    and PARTITION_NAME LIKE 'SYS_P%'
    ;

@runme

ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1
  SET INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'));
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1
  SET INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'));
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_1.TABLE_3
  SET INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'));
```

Yes, the script is semi-manual, but I think it's more safety.

`ALTER TABLE ... INTERVAL` it's need for droping last partition.

Interval must be same that it was before