# How to drop multiple interval partitions based on date?

Tags: oracle, partition

I have a table based on daily partitions.

I can drop a paritition using the below query

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE('19-DEC-2017','dd-MON-yyyy'))
```

How can I drop all the partitions (multiple partitions) before 15 days?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle : Drop multiple partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110948/oracle-drop-multiple-partitions)

Comment: I understand the delete based on name. I am trying to check whether any alternatives based on date range.

Comment: You can drop partition on name as well. `ALTER TABLE sales DROP PARTITION sales_q1_2008, sales_q2_2008,
     sales_q3_2008, sales_q4_2008;` . I dont thing there is something on date range

Comment: @XING - THANK YOU

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use PL/SQL like this.

```
DECLARE
    CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION, -14758);

   ts TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
   FOR aPart IN (SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE') LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
      IF ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '15' DAY THEN
      BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
      EXCEPTION
            WHEN CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE SET INTERVAL ()';
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME;
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE SET INTERVAL( INTERVAL ''1'' DAY )';            
      END;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: In the table USER_TAB_PARTITIONS, high value is having "TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00'" . So any changes I will have to make?

Comment: Why is this 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' required? Why we cannot directly use aPart.HIGH_VALUE?

Comment: Because `HIGH_VALUE` is data type `LONG` which has many limitations. You cannot use it directly, `IF aPart.HIGH_VALUE < ...` or `FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS  WHERE HIGH_VALUE < ...` will fail.

Comment: how can we prevent getting the exception "Last partition in the range section cannot be dropped"

Comment: I put it in my answer. The last (i.e. the initaly created) partition you have to drop manually. Once the last partition is dropped you will not get the error again.

Comment: can we handle this "ORA-14758"? Any named exception? I am planning to keep it in exception block

Comment: :)  Sorry for that. But ur answer is extremely informative.

Comment: Regarding "Why we cannot directly use aPart.HIGH_VALUE?", it is because this column is stored as a LONG in the database.  It is hence a string representation of that timestamp, not the timestamp itself.

Answer (score 3):

For *interval partitioned tables* (that you probably use based on the exception `ORA-14758`) you may profit from using the [*partition_extended_name*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Syntax-for-Schema-Objects-and-Parts-in-SQL-Statements.html#GUID-FED2E424-3F06-4B2B-88D2-DE043CA6E0E4) syntax.

You need not know the partition name, you reference the partition with a DATE, e.g.

```
alter table INT_PART drop partition for (DATE'2018-09-01')
```

So to drop your last 15 partitions starting with the current day this loop is to be performed:

```
declare
 v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
begin
  for cur in (select  
                trunc(sysdate,'MM') - numtodsinterval(rownum - 1, 'day') my_month
              from dual connect by level <= 15) 
  loop
     v_sql := q'[alter table INT_PART drop partition for (DATE']'||
                 to_char(cur.my_month,'YYYY-MM-DD')||q'[')]';
     execute immediate v_sql;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

You must use `execute immediate`as the DATEin the `ALTER TABLE` statement must by static.
Following statements are generated and executed:

```
alter table INT_PART drop partition for (DATE'2018-09-01')
alter table INT_PART drop partition for (DATE'2018-08-31')
....
alter table INT_PART drop partition for (DATE'2018-08-19')
alter table INT_PART drop partition for (DATE'2018-08-18')
```

Additional to the exception `ORA-14758` (that I ignore - see the note below) you should handle the exception

> ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist

dependent on you business this should be probably ignored - for this day no partition exists (and you will never reference this day using the partition dictionary metadata).

**Note** to workaround the `ORA-14758  Last partition in the range section cannot be dropped` exception you may use this little trick.

I create a *dummy* partition (without an extent) called `P_MINVALUE` that plays the role of the interval start in the far past and it will therefore never be dropped.

```
CREATE TABLE int_part
      (
     transaction_date TIMESTAMP not null,
     vc_pad VARCHAR2(100)
      )
     SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
     PARTITION BY RANGE (transaction_date) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
      (
     PARTITION P_MINVALUE  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
   );
```

Comment: Syntax `PARTITION FOR (DATE '...')` is called "Partition Extended Name"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for pointing this out. I edited the link. Fancy way is that it must be written with underscores `partition_extended_name` to find it in the Oracle documentation.