# How to drop partitions from tables across multiple schemas?

Tags: oracle, plsql, partitioning

I am trying to write a Procedure which essentially drops partitions from several tables which are stored in multiple schemas. End goal is to then create a dbms scheduler which will run this procedure every day and check for partitions that hold data older than 6 months. How to add functionality of looking for partitions across multiple schemas ?

I have created a Procedure which drops a partition only from a specific table.

```
PROCEDURE purge_ops_log_range_parts IS
   BEGIN
      FOR partition_rec IN (SELECT partition_name
                                  ,high_value
                              FROM user_tab_partitions
                             WHERE table_name =
                                   'OPSWIRE_LOG_RANGE_PARTS')
      LOOP
         IF SYSDATE >= add_months(to_date(substr(partition_rec.high_value
                                                ,12
                                                ,19)
                                         ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                 ,6)
         THEN
            execute_immediate('ALTER TABLE OPS_LOG_RANGE_PARTS DROP PARTITION ' ||
                              partition_rec.partition_name);
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
   END purge_ops_log_range_parts;
```

Output is deleting partition from a specific table only however it does not look for multiple tables in various schemas.

Comment: Using `SUBSTR(partition_rec.HIGH_VALUE, ...)` is rather risky. I would recommend this syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089186/drop-multiple-partitions-based-on-date like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||partition_rec.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts; IF SYSDATE >= add_months(ts, 6) THEN...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS` or `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS` views instead of `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS`. The former two views contain a `TABLE_OWNER` (i.e. schema) column which should help you accomplish your goal.

You can then parameterize your procedure to take the owner and table names as parameters:

```
PROCEDURE purge_ops_log_range_parts(pinOwner      IN VARCHAR2,
                                    pinTable_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR partition_rec IN (SELECT partition_name
                              ,high_value
                          FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS
                         WHERE TABLE_OWNER = pinOwner AND
                               table_name = pinTable_name)
  LOOP
     IF SYSDATE >= add_months(to_date(substr(partition_rec.high_value
                                            ,12
                                            ,19)
                                     ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                             ,6)
     THEN
        execute_immediate('ALTER TABLE ' || pinOwner || '.' ||
                             pinTable_name || ' DROP PARTITION ' ||
                             partition_rec.partition_name);
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END purge_ops_log_range_parts;
```

Best of luck.