# How to drop partitions based on specific retention period?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, sysdate

```
    PROCEDURE purge_partitions
   (
      p_owner            IN VARCHAR2
     ,p_name             IN VARCHAR2
     ,p_retention_period IN NUMBER
   ) IS
   BEGIN
      FOR partition_rec IN (SELECT partition_name
                                  ,high_value
                              FROM dba_tab_partitions
                             WHERE table_owner = p_owner
                               AND table_name = p_name)

      --drop partitions older than specified retention preriod
      LOOP
         IF SYSDATE >= add_months(to_date(substr(partition_rec.high_value
                                                ,12
                                                ,19)
                                         ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                 ,p_retention_period)
         THEN
            execute_immediate('ALTER TABLE ' || p_owner || '.' ||
                              p_name || ' DROP PARTITION ' ||
                              partition_rec.partition_name);
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
   END purge_partitions;
```

I am trying to add futher granularity to the loop statement so rather than just dropping partitions monthly, I'd like to extend this by days too. Also just FYI the records are fetched from a Config tabe which includes details of partitioned tables(table owner, name and retention period - data type NUMBER). Therefore, im not sure how to go about this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again and again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148136/dropping-partitioned-tables-with-global-indexes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936930/how-to-drop-partitions-from-tables-across-multiple-schemas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837937/how-to-create-a-procedure-in-oracle-pl-sql-to-drop-partitions-of-a-table-every-m (and even again and again with the same fault)?

Comment: What is `p_retention_period`? Days or months? Or even weeks, years, hours, ...?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit first of all, although I am asking questions about the same procedure, the questions I asked previously were different to what I am asking in this post so im not quiet sure what you mean by asking the same questions again and again with the same fault?. Also p_retention_period is months atm however i'd like to change this to day, weeks,etc.

Comment: With fault I mean `to_date(substr(partition_rec.high_value, ...`. If you call your procedure for example like `purge_partitions('OWNER_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME', 6);` - how do you know wether `6` means "6 weeks" or "6 days"?

Comment: Yh so thats my actual question, how can I differentiate 6 months, 6 weeks, 6 days in the code?I am aware of the HIGH_VALUE issue - i'll make the change soon.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the colunm HIGH_VALUE has datatype LONG, so it is quite hard to use in PL/SQL.
But you do not need to use is anyway, there is construct [ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION FOR (to_date(....))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54203450/how-to-drop-partitions-based-on-specific-retention-period) . So you do not have to deal with generated partition name at all.

> The following example drops the September 2007 interval partition from the sales table. There are only local indexes so no indexes are invalidated.

```
ALTER TABLE sales DROP PARTITION FOR(TO_DATE('01-SEP-2007','dd-MON-yyyy'));
```

PS: it seems that this SQL extension was patented by Oracle.

Comment: Since TO wants to write a generic procedure I would not recommend to use the partition-extended name. Imagine you run `... DROP PARTITION FOR (DATE '2019-01-01')` and your partition interval is 1 Month - you would drop the current partition. Or the partition interval is 12 hours - you would drop too few partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You procedure has syntax errors (e.g. `execute_immediate(...)`).

A working procedure would be this one. You should name it `drop_partitions` rather than `purge_partitions` because you **drop** the partitions. "Purge" would be also possible, with `ALTER TABLE ... TRUNCATE PARTITION ...`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE drop_partitions(
   p_owner IN VARCHAR2, 
   p_name IN VARCHAR2, 
   p_retention_period IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) IS

    ts TIMESTAMP;

    CURSOR TabPartitions IS 
    SELECT partition_name, high_value 
    FROM dba_tab_partitions 
    WHERE table_owner = p_owner 
        AND table_name = p_name;

BEGIN

    FOR partition_rec IN TabPartitions LOOP 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||partition_rec.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
        IF ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - p_retention_period THEN
            --drop partitions older than specified retention preriod
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p_owner ||'.'||p_name 
                 || ' DROP PARTITION ' || partition_rec.partition_name || ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END drop_partitions;
```

Then you could call this procedure for example like

```
purge_partitions('OWNER_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME', INTERVAL '60' DAY);
purge_partitions('OWNER_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME', NUMTODSINTERVAL(100, 'day'));
```

Note, you have also `YEAR TO MONTH INTERVAL` in Oracle. If you like to use this also you have to overload the procedure, i.e. create a second procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE drop_partitions(
   p_owner IN VARCHAR2, 
   p_name IN VARCHAR2, 
   p_retention_period IN INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH) IS

   ... rest would be exactly the same as above.
```

For be aware that for `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` you get exceptions for calculations like `timestamp '2019-03-31 00:00:00' - INTERVAL '1' MONTH`, see [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208)

Comment: How can I declare the cursor TabPartitions in the package spec?

Comment: Simply write it in package spec instead in a procedure.