# Selecting data from Oracle database standard table all_tab_partitions with a condition of sysdate-7 on the bases on high_value column

Tags: database, oracle, select

Query:

```
select partition_name 
from all_tab_partitions 
where high_value < sysdate-7;
```

Error:

> [Error] Execution (9: 51): ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

I have already tried `to_date` and `trunc` but that didn't work.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089186/how-to-drop-multiple-interval-partitions-based-on-date/48089939#48089939

Comment: ... or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52171170/4808122) if you can use *partition extended names* and avoid access to `all_tab_partitions`.