# drop hourly list partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `start_time` field of type `date` and have created a list hourly partition called `start_time_h` of type `to_char(start_time, 'hh').`
But now it’s impossible to drop the partition in any way, I tried it through execute immediate, directly through alter table. Every time an error occurs that the rage is different, etc., how can I drop an hourly partition from `trunc(sysdate - 1/24, 'hh')` to `trunc(sysdate + 1/24, 'hh'),` that is, it needs to drop two partitions since I insert data from `trunc(sysdate - 1/24, 'hh')` to `trunc(sysdate + 1/24, 'hh')`

Comment: The table definition would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I would suggest this one:

```
DECLARE

    start_time DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1/24, 'hh');
    end_time DATE:= TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1/24, 'hh');
    aDate DATE;

BEGIN

    aDate := start_time ; 
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE SOFT_CALLS DROP PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE('''|| TO_CHAR(aDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')||''', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI''))';
        aDate := aDate + 1/24;
        exit WHEN aDate >= end_time ;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Another approach is this one: [How to drop multiple interval partitions based on date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089186/how-to-drop-multiple-interval-partitions-based-on-date/48089939#48089939)

Comment: it shows ORA-14702; ORA-06512; The partition number is invalid or out-of-range

Comment: Like in your previous question it is very hard to provide any solution if you don't provide the table definition. Based on the information given in your question, this is a working solution. Otherwise have a look at liked answer.